# Vue Slider Component - Enable drag-end and on-click updates concurently

Tags: vue.js, slider, click, dragendjs, vue-slider-component

I'm using `vue-slider-component` in my project. By default, it is `clickable` i.e. it applies update (calls desired method) on click event. But it also continuously applies updates while dragging, from start to end point. What I wanted is to apply update only `once` when slider stops at end point. So I added `@drag-end` attribute. Now the problem is that I can click on slider, and it animates (slides) but no updates are applied, due to `@drag-end` attribute. How can I remain `@drag-end` feature but concurently enable update apply on click?

Comment: please post code

Answer (score 2):

I think setting the lazy attribute to true might fix this.

```
v-on:change="updateApcs()" :lazy="true"
```